# как присвоить класс к рандомным элементам

Tags: javascript, html, классы, случайные-числа

```
<div id=“blocks”>
    <div class=“block”></div>
    <div class=“block”></div>
    <div class=“block”></div>
    <div class=“block”></div>
    <div class=“block”></div>
    <div class=“block”></div>
    <div class=“block”></div>
</div>
```

нужно рандомно выбрать 3-4 элемента и присвоить им класс active, написать на чистом JS, не на Jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let toSelect = 3;
const blocks = document.getElementById('blocks').children;
const used = [];

while (toSelect !== 0) {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * blocks.length);

  if (used.lenght === blocks.length) break;
  if (used.includes(index)) continue;

  blocks[index].classList.add('active');
  used.push(index);
  toSelect--;
}
```

```css
.block {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #ddd;
}

#blocks {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="blocks">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Извините, не могли бы Вы объяснить, для чего используется в данном js коде ```const used = []; if (used.lenght === blocks.length) break; if (used.includes(index)) continue; used.push(index);```

Comment: проверяем был ли такой блок уже выбран или нет

Comment: А, точно, спасибо